# How do I find the amount of minor page faults using "time"?

Tags: unix, time

How do I use the `time` utility to show the number of minor page faults?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the man page for `time`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time):

```
%R    Number of minor, or recoverable, page faults.  These are  faults
      for pages that are not valid but which have not yet been claimed
      by other virtual pages.  Thus the data  in  the  page  is  still
      valid but the system tables must be updated.
```

and

```
-f FORMAT, --format=FORMAT
      Specify  output format, possibly overriding the format specified
      in the environment variable TIME.
```

Thus:

```
time -f %R command
```

Comment: Nice feature! What OS is this, please, thanks! (I don't recall any options for the time cmd on Solaris or AIX, but don't have access to them to confirm)

Comment: @shelter: That man page is a combination, and this was listed under `GNU time`.